# Dual boot drive sharing for Ubuntu and Windows 10

Tags: dual-boot, partitioning, xubuntu, gparted, windows-10

I have a laptop with 128gb SSD on which I have windows 10 installed and a 1tb on drive which I have Xubuntu.
Now I want to shrink the size of the Xubuntu partition and want to use the unallocated space as a media partition for both windows and Xubuntu. And I want that partition to show up as D drive in Windows. Can anyone help me with this.

Answer (score 1):

1. Make a Live USB with Ubuntu ([tutorial here](https://tutorials.ubuntu.com/tutorial/tutorial-create-a-usb-stick-on-windows#1)) or create a Live CD with Ubuntu ISO
2. Run Live Ubuntu and install **GParted** or open it if is installed.
3. In the left side, on top, select the hard disk (1TB HDD) -> [ /dev/sd**x** (1024GB) ]
4. Right-click on the partition you want to resize, then click **Resize/Move**
5. Change the **New size (MiB)** value with the size you want on Xubuntu partition
6. Click on **Resize/Move** button
7. Edit -> Apply All Operations
8. Create your new partition.

**NOTE: When resize, is the possibility of data loss. Please create a backup with your data!**